# Rails: i18n parameters that are also translated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n, i18n-gem

I'm having difficulty finding the answer for my question, but it may just be that I have no idea how to phrase it. In svenfuchs's yml files in his rails-i18n repo, he has this listed under error:

```
format: #{attribute}#{message}
```

and below that he specifies possible error messages. It's really nifty, as it automatically translated error messages for me.

I'd like to use this format to translate headers and buttons. In Japanese, we'd say "FAQ Create" while in English we'd say "Create FAQ", so I can't just print out those translations and I'd like to not have to make each button's translation myself (a.k.a. `create_faq: FAQを作る`).

So far I've got in my view: `t('button.format'), :attribute => "faq", :message => "create"`

ja.yml:

```
model:
  faq: FAQ
button:
  format: #{attribute}#{message}
  messages:
    create: を作る
```

But that just prints out `faqcreate` for Japanese. What I'm trying to do is access the translations of model.faq and button.messages.create to pass as the parameters. Anybody know how?

p.s. messages: was also plural in the working errors message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I'm so stupid, I keep answering my questions right after I finally decided to ask for help;;; for anybody interested, just pass in another t(' '), so:

```
t('button.format', :attribute t('model.faq'), :message t('button.messages.create'))
```